# Async task - need way to resume

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My AsyncTask loads image thumbnails from URLs and displays them one by one in a Custom ListView.  The Activity is called ViewThumbsActivity.

It might take a minute for all the thumbnails to load if there are a lot.

I have functionality where a user can click on the thumbnail, and it opens the bigger image in a new Activity (ViewImageActivity)

The problem is this:

In ViewThumbsActivity, I cancel the AsyncTask in the onStop, so when the user clicks on a thumbnail to see a bigger one, the AsyncTask is cancelled and the rest of the thumbnails in the activity stop loading.  So when they close ViewImageActivity to go back to ViewThumbsActivity, the thumbnails have stopped loading.

You might suggest that I do not cancel the AsyncTask in the onStop?
I'm tempted to do that BUT:

The user can also *select* thumbnails (before they are loaded), and then choose to go to ActivityLast.  When they are in ActivityLast, there is no point continuing the AsyncTask in the previous activity to load the thumbnails.  And if I don't stop the AsyncTask, the ActivityLast runs very slowly!

BUT: The user could always click BACK and select more thumbs, so I guess I want to resume loading thumbnails if they click back.

I tried this here code from github, but it didnt seem to work for me?

http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/pausing-and-resuming-background-work-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting ViewThumbActivity from ActivityLast, use  `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`
Then in  `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` stop AsyncTask.

Also see if [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if I do what you suggest then the AsyncTask will be stopped when ViewThumbActivity is loaded when the user presses the back key from ActivityLast?

Comment: onActivity result will be called when started activity (ViewThumbActivity) finishes.